# Python join two texts

Tags: python, text

I am new to python and I am trying to write python program that takes each text line from file 1 and file 2, merge it and writes to 3 file. File 1 contains for example text in first line "The rain is " and file 2 contains in first line "is in Spain.". It needs to merge matching characters. I also want to trim before that last character from file one and first character from second file. The final result should be "The rain is in Spain." in third file.

```
with open("file_1.", 'r') as f_1,\
open("file_2.", 'r') as f_2,\
open("file_3.", 'w') as f_3:\
```

Comment: Hi shorty, here at Stack Overflow it is asked that you at least make an attempt with coding. Even if you just show an example of importing from the text files. 
I will hint though once the text files have been read and set to a variable it is very easy to concatenate them and push them to a new file

Comment: @Pittsie It's more than just concatenation though, it's finding the matching characters so that the output is "The rain is in Spain", not "The rain **is is** in Spain". Point absolutely taken about some effort needed from the OP first.

Comment: Okay, at least the question has been edited with startings of some code... that's something.

Answer (score 0):

You can scan through the starting points in the first string looking for substrings (to the end of the first string) that are also the start of the second string.  Any newlines will have to be stripped first.

```
with open("file1") as f:
    str1 = f.read()

with open("file2") as f:
    str2 = f.read()

while str1.endswith("\n"):
    str1 = str1[:-1]
    
for pos in range(len(str1)):
    if str2.startswith(str1[pos:]):
        str1 = str1[:pos]
        break

with open("file3", "w") as fout:
    fout.write(str1 + str2)
```